# How do I add a shadow to an entire table using just CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a subtle shadow to make my table look raised.

Just using CSS, how do I do that?

Comment: What CSS version? CSS3 is not compatible on some browsers so I'm guessing the box-shadow tag will not work.  but fyi the other browsers have different tags   .shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
}

Comment: Preferably as many browsers as possible. But I might just default to CSS3 if that's what I can get.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`table { box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999; }`

More box-shadow examples here: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: Right, what I didn't mention was that you have to include vendor-prefixes to make it work in some browsers. The `-moz-` prefix is for Firefox, for Chrome/Safari you can use `-webkit-` and for Konqueror `-khtml-`

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 has the box-shadow declaration. Check [this article](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) for more information.